# Trigger Lambda multiple times on S3 file upload

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have a s3 bucket and I have configured s3 event on lambda to trigger whenever file uploaded on s3 but I want to trigger lambda 100 times on each file is uploaded.This is something to do some performance testing and find throttling point.This what i tried to upload s3 file using lambda so that s3 will trigger second lambda on file upload.But this is triggering one lambda on each file upload but I want lambda should trigger 100 times on each file upload.

> One S3 upload should trigger 100 times same lambda

test lambda to upload file

```
'use strict';
const proxy = require('proxy-agent');
const
    AWS = require( 'aws-sdk' ),
    S3  = new AWS.S3();
    AWS.config.update(
        {
            httpOptions: {agent: proxy('http://myprox.com:80')}
        }
    );

exports.handler = async ( event, context ) => {
    console.log( `FUNCTION STARTED: ${new Date()}` );
    try {
        for (let index = 0; index < 50; index++) {
            console.log('Counter :',index)
            const start= Date.now()
            const result= await S3.putObject( {
                Bucket: 'test-bucket',
                Key: index+'my.json',
                Body: JSON.stringify( {
                   "Id":index,
               })
           } ).promise();
           const end= Date.now();
           console.log(`Time taken for counter: ${index} to upload S3 is: ${end-start} ms`)
           console.log('S3 result counter'+index,JSON.stringify(result))  

        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.log('S3 error',JSON.stringify(error))  
    }

};
```

Comment: You could trigger one lambda from your S3 event that puts 100 messages on an SQS queue, and then each of those messages triggers your testing lambda.

Comment: Rather than creating an artificial testing setup that won't actually test your desired final state, I would recommend trying to emulate the actual situation that you want to handle. So, if you want to handle people uploading 100s of files per second, then you should try to upload 100s of files to trigger the same situation. Otherwise, all your testing might not actually prove the situation you desire.

Comment: You could just call `Invoke` 100 times to trigger Lambda 100 times, instead of doing it via an Amazon S3 trigger. Make sure the payload contains the same information that would be provided with an S3 upload trigger.